# How do redirect in Ajax Post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to redirect Ajax post in a success function

Here's the code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/create-room/",
    data:{
      targetedUser,
    },
    success: function(data) {
      // How to redirect in here??
    }
});
```

Comment: Redirect to which location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `window.location.replace` or `window.location.href` inside the `success` function :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/create-room/",
    data:{
        targetedUser,
    },
    success: function(data) {
        window.location.replace("url"); //Simulate HTTP redirection
        //Or
        window.location.href = "url"; //Simulate click on a link
    }
});
```

For more information you could check **[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-using-jquery)**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You might explain the difference between the two options.

Comment: Or just `window.location = 'url'`.

Comment: Thanks @michael for your intervention, `window.location` is the same as `window.location.href`.

Comment: Yes, they're referencing the same thing, just a bit shorter (: